# Find an extension of section of vector bundle along piecewise smooth curve

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles

Suppose $M$ be a manifold and $v, w$ be (smooth) sections of vector bundle $E \to M$ along a curve $\gamma, \gamma':[0,1] \to M$.

Assume that $\gamma$ and $\gamma'$ don't meet excepting at their initial point(t = 0) and each of them don't intersect theirselves. In addition, $v(0) = w(0)$.

Then, does there exist an extension of $s \in \Gamma(E)$ satisfies $s \circ \gamma = v$ and $s \circ \gamma' = w$?

I have an idea using local spherical coordinates and bump function, but maybe there exist another method to do this. Any suggestions is appreciated.

**ADD**

We need additional assumption for making sense. $\{ \dot{\gamma}(0),\dot{\gamma}'(0)\}$ is linearly independent in $T_{\gamma(0)} M$.

Comment: If $\gamma$ and $\gamma'$ meet at $p=\gamma(0)=\gamma'(0)$, then it may be the case that $v(p)\neq w(p)$, in which case no such extension would exist. Even if $v(p)=w(p)$, the two sections may fail to meet smoothly.

Comment: @Kajelad What does "fail to meet smoothly" mean?

Comment: Essentially that no local extension exists which restricts to both $v$ and $w$. As an example, take $M=\mathbb{R}$, $\gamma(t)=t$, $\gamma'(t)=-t$, $v(\gamma(t))=t$, and $w(\gamma'(t))=t$.

Comment: Ah, I understand what you mean. I need some more assumptions.

Comment: What precisely is your idea? It seems like using adapted coordinates and a partition of unity would indeed be the most straightforward approach.